# Cann i use Ajax requests in an Hybrid App/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap

I am working on an hybrid app with phonegap and my question is does Ajax work with phonegap and can i put javascript with html in one html file?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: *does Ajax work* - yes, since phonegap is just a browser component showing your webpage

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks and can i put them both in one file like in the browser with a script part in the html file or do i have to seperate them?

Comment: actually, I've misled you - please ignore my comment about browser component (or webview as it is actually called) - though, AJAX as such will work, since AJAX isn't actually a specific library, rather a concept implemented in many different ways - as for having inline script - I can't see why it wouldn't work, but in the one phonegap app I've had to deal with, there was no inline script

Comment: @JaromandaX In my script Ajax doesn't work even when i make a separate file only for the script but an $.document onclick function from jQuery works

Comment: @JaromandaX Maybe is my problem that i used a post ajax type?